# Is this GCC 12.1 const problem a bug or feature? "Attempts to call non-const function with const object"

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc12

We're seeing C++ code, that compiles successfully in GCC 11.3 and Visual Studio 2022, have issues with GCC 12.1.  The code is on [Compiler Explorer](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer): https://godbolt.org/z/6PYEcsd1h  (Thanks to @NathanPierson for simplifying it some.)

Basically, a template class is deciding to try to call a non-const base class function in a const function, even though a const overload is available.  This appears to be some sort of compiler bug, but it could be some weird new C++ rule I don't understand.  Does this represent a compiler bug?

```
struct BaseClass
{
    // Commenting this non-const function out will also fix the compilation.
    int* baseDevice() { return nullptr; }
    const int* baseDevice() const { return nullptr; }
};

template <class ObjectClass>
struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

};

template <class ObjectClass>
struct TopClass : DerivedClass<ObjectClass>
{
  public:
    virtual int failsToCompile() const
    {
      // This should choose to call the const function, but it tries to call the non-const version.
      if (BaseClass::baseDevice())
         return 4;

      return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TopClass<int> x;
}
```

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'int TopClass<ObjectClass>::failsToCompile() const [with ObjectClass = ConcreteObject]':
<source>:27:17:   required from here
<source>:30:32: error: passing 'const TopClass<ConcreteObject>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   30 |       if (BaseClass::baseDevice())
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:14:15: note:   in call to 'MyDevice* BaseClass::baseDevice()'
   14 |     MyDevice* baseDevice() { return nullptr; }
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: You need to declare the function itself as const. Has always been so.

Comment: @MarkRansom Isn't it? `const MyDevice* baseDevice() const { return nullptr; }`

Comment: It _does_ look fishy. Workarounds: `this->baseDevice()` or `DerivedClass<ObjectClass>::baseDevice()`

Comment: Made the example [slightly more minimal](https://godbolt.org/z/7d1enW9dP), a lot of the class hierarchy there isn't necessary to reproduce this. I do need `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` though and can't just put the methods in `DerivedClass`. Curious.

Comment: Thanks Nathan.  I had tried to remove some stuff but then it worked... :)

Comment: Congrats Rob!  Finding a compiler bug is a feather in one's cap!  (And thanks to Ted for filing a bug report!)

Comment: We've got a 10,000,000 line codebase for our project, so that makes it a bit easier. ;)

Comment: @RobL Is that all? :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Is this gcc 12.1 const problem a bug or feature

It's a bug. I filed a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105637) and the issue has already been verified coming from [this commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;h=2decd2cabe5a4f).

The ticket has been assigned and the resolution has a targeted milestone of version 12.2 - so we can hope for a quick fix.